# Set Default Value in a Formula Date/Time Field

Tags: formula-field, datetime, time-dependent-workflow

I am looking to create a formula date/time field that will give me for example 12/05/2014 3:00 PM for today and then tomorrow it changes to 12/06/2014 3:00 PM.  The date but not the time will change daily.

Comment: what have you tried?  folks at SFSE appreciate some effort on the part of posters and then will jump in. Have you read: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DATETIMEVALUE(DATE(year(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)), 
month(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)), day(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)))) + 7 + 11.50/24
```

This will default to date : `+ 5:00pm`